# Unexpected behavior of the Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster(3.11.2 version) in the 4 DC.

Sometimes, the nodes in the each DC start work very much. There are a lot of read-repair operations, a lot of successed hints.

Metrics:

- org.apache.cassandra.metrics.HintsService.HintsSucceeded.count[image: org.apache.cassandra.metrics.HintsService.HintsSucceeded.count]
- org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ReadRepair.RepairedBlocking.count[image: org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ReadRepair.RepairedBlocking.count]
- org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.TotalBlockedTasks.transport.Native-Transport-Requests.count][image: org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.TotalBlockedTasks.transport.Native-Transport-Requests.count]
- org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.PendingTasks.request.MutationStage.value[image: org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.PendingTasks.request.MutationStage.value]

It happens for about 1 hour. In this time, nodes lost connection with each other and itself:

```
[cluster3-timeouter-0] com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - [] Defuncting Connection[/{{local_ip}}:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false]
    com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ConnectionException: [/{{local_ip}}:9042] Heartbeat query timed out
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$11.onTimeout(Connection.java:1191)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler$1.run(Connection.java:1380)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:625)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:700)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:428)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
```

I don't understand, why it happened. It isn't compaction, because there are no anomalies in the compaction metrics. Are there any ideas why it happens?

Comment: It almost looks like there's a scheduled job which either runs on a table at consistency QUORUM with a high read repair chance.  Or it's running at consistency ALL.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a scheduled job, but unfortunately I haven't found any information about it in the cassandra documentation(( Maybe you know, what kind of job could it be and can I configure the schedule time for this job?

P.S.: there are no any scheduled jobs for this action in the OS.